# cmake CMAKE_COMMAND path

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, path

I created the simplest possible CMakeLists file. I invoked cmake with the path to that CMakeLists file. Cmake created a Makefile. Inside that makefile I see the variable CMAKE_COMMAND set to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake

I'm trying to understand cmake at a high level; what it does and how it is used. I don't understand why python is involved at all in that path. Nothing in my CMakeLists file involves python. Why is THAT version of the cmake executable being used?

When I type "which cmake" I get /usr/local/bin/cmake which makes sense to me. So if that is the cmake binary I get when invoking cmake, why is it using that python-based version in the makefile it generates?

Comment: So, what type the file `/usr/local/bin/cmake` has? Is it a binary? Or is it a symlink?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is a binary.

Comment: Which Linux distro do you use? Which package(s) contains given files?

Comment: @Tsyvarev It's Ubuntu. I'll have to check which packages. So does it at least seem strange to you that python is in the CMAKE_COMMAND path? Am I correct in finding this unusual from your experience?

Comment: I guess `/usr/local/bin/cmake` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake` belongs to the same package, and the first one just calls the second. By checking the packages you could verify this hypothesis. Also, I don't think that one should worry about that difference of executables. If everything works, then why one need to bother about **internals** of CMake?

Comment: @Tsyvarev The binaries are different when I compare them. The issue is the system is not working. I need to use python 3.6. I add that requirement to the CMakeLists file and it runs fine and finds python 3.6 on the system. But the Makefile it generates has that python 2.7 path and make is failing to complete properly. I hypothesize that it's because the cmake executable in the python 2.7 path is not compatible with python 3.6. But for the life of my I can't get that darn python 2.7 path to stop showing up! Even when CMakeLists is only two lines!

Comment: "I need to use python 3.6" - It should be no conflict in requiring Python 3.6 for your project and using python 2.7 by CMake itself. Anyway, if this is an actual problem, then please update your question post to reflect it (with the relevant code and with exact error messages).

Comment: And what about checking Ubuntu packages? E.g. `cmake` package in Ubuntu 20.04 [provides file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/cmake/filelist) `/usr/bin/cmake`, not `/usr/local/bin/cmake`. It smells like `/usr/local/bin/cmake` is installed with some **Python package** (e.g. with pip), not by Ubuntu itself. Please, check these aspects in your system.